# polymer dom-repeat filter render issue

Tags: javascript, html, filter, polymer, render

I have a google-map elements and render some google-map-marker like code below

```
<google-map>
    <template id="markerList" 
        is="dom-repeat" items="{{response}}" 
        initial-count="10" 
        filter="{{computeFilterMap(searchString)}}">

        <google-map-marker 
            latitude="{{item.lat}}" longitude="{{item.lon}}" 
            title="{{item.location}}" 
            animation="DROP" 
            icon="{{computeOnOffIcon(item.onOff)}}" 
            on-google-map-marker-open="markerClick">
                <h4>{{item.location}}</h4>
                <div><!-- other info --></div>
        </google-map-marker>
    </template>
</google-map>
```

also, I have a filter function for searching.

```
computeFilterMap = function(string){
    if (!string) {
    // set filter to null to disable filtering
        return null;
    } else {
        string = string.toLowerCase();
        return function(movil) {
            // Location
            var location = movil.location.toLowerCase();
            // true or false
            var motor = movil.onOff? "On" : "Off";

            return (location.indexOf(string) != -1 || 
                motor.indexOf(string) != -1 || 
                pat.indexOf(string) != -1);
        };
    }
}
```

Some data:

```
[
    {
        "location": "antofagasta",
        "lat": -23.6283541,
        "lon": -70.474539,
        "motor": true
    },
    {
        "location": "Calama",
        "lat": -22.4612687,
        "lon": -68.9584051,
        "motor": false
    },
    {
        "location": "Las Vegas",
        "lat": 36.1246738,
        "lon": -115.455193,
        "motor": false
    }
]
```

the issue:
the filter function works fine, it show the marker in the right place (lat, lon) but the infowindows of google-map-marker doesn't render properly, it shows the info of the first element of the list.

I try:

- I try to call the render function of the dom-repeat when the user open the info window
- And when paper-input change, when user interact

Comment: Can you include sample data in the question?

Comment: Hi tony, I found this:
https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map/issues/263

it's seems that is the problem

Comment: Ah, interesting. Thanks for the update.